# TSQL: Vary JOIN constraints depending on possible joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say we have the following simple tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #TabA
(
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 int
);

INSERT INTO #TabA VALUES(1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,3), (4,4,4);

CREATE TABLE #TabB
(
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 int
);
```

I want to write a query so that if the the data in #TabB is:

```
INSERT INTO #TabB VALUES(1,1,6), (2,2,7), (3,3,8), (4,4,9);
```

then the results will be the same as the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #TabA A
INNER JOIN #TabB B
   ON A.col1 = B.col1
   AND A.col2 = B.col2
```

but if the data in #TabB is instead:

`INSERT INTO #TabB VALUES(1,2,6), (2,3,7), (3,4,8), (4,5,9);`

then the results will be the same as the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #TabA A
INNER JOIN #TabB B
   ON A.col1 = B.col1
```

In other words, the second `JOIN` constraint only kicks in if there is any data that would match it - otherwise it uses a looser joining criteria.

Is there an elegant way to do this rather than writing some `IF` statements?

Comment: You can conditionally join but I'm not certain that is a complete solution. It does not help that you have two distinct sets of TabB rows where joining on two columns works or does not work for every row. Your sample data should include both types of matching (within the same sample) and you should clearly show what you expect (and why).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #TabB B
LEFT JOIN #TabA A1
   ON B.col1 = A1.col1
   AND B.col2 = A1.col2
LEFT JOIN #TabA A2
   ON B.col1 = A2.col1
   AND A1.col1 IS NULL -- First join had no match
```

This can be used with some coalesce expressions or perhaps a `CROSS APPLY` to gather the results.

```
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT A1.Col1, A1.Col2, A1.Col3 WHERE A1.Col1 IS NOT NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT A2.Col1, A2.Col2, A2.Col3 WHERE A2.Col1 IS NOT NULL
) A
```

You can change the above to an `OUTER APPLY` to see no-match cases.

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8be75592c96f7f7af66b50b9988e87ac) for a demo using `OUTER APPLY` and a few extra values to show multiple match cases.